# Access token and refresh token expiry time is always 1199 in spring boot oauth impl

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have implemented Oauth2 using springboot framework. I am able to get the JWT token from the OAuth Server as below:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsib2F1dGgyLXJlc291cmNlIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InJycnIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkX3Byb2ZpbGVfaW5mbyJdLCJleHAiOjE2MTA4MTk4OTIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlVTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiZDExZWIxYmMtYjUyMy00NjMxLTkxMWItMDA1Yjc1YTkyNDgwIiwiQ3VzdG9tIFBheWxvYWQiOiJycnJyLWFiY2QiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJjbGllbnRhcHAifQ.ppqpoZGTIeNaLfWCxXk9lOVAjz8Vamu0ffT1pd86V_g",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsib2F1dGgyLXJlc291cmNlIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InJycnIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkX3Byb2ZpbGVfaW5mbyJdLCJhdGkiOiJkMTFlYjFiYy1iNTIzLTQ2MzEtOTExYi0wMDViNzVhOTI0ODAiLCJleHAiOjE2MTA4MjEwOTIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlVTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiMzFjZWQ0OGUtZWZmOC00OGMyLWJkOTYtYjdhMjIwYmIxYjcxIiwiQ3VzdG9tIFBheWxvYWQiOiJycnJyLWFiY2QiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJjbGllbnRhcHAifQ.1u12wG4WyOmETFD-1QXrUXLO_FdJkBmxz2vX1xMHWPE",
    "expires_in": 1199,
    "scope": "read_profile_info",
    "Custom Payload": "rrrr-abcd",
    "jti": "d11eb1bc-b523-4631-911b-005b75a92480"
}
```

I am having following two query related to above response:

1. Event though there is two token in response, access token and refresh token but why there is only one expiry time in the response object.
2. I tired to reset the expiry to some different value but i am always seeing the same expiry time as if my changes is not reflecting somehow. Please find below code change which I have used to update the access token and refresh token expiry but it is not working:

   @Configuration

   ```
   @EnableAuthorizationServer

   public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter { 
   ...
   @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("clientapp").secret(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token").authorities("READ_ONLY_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read_profile_info").resourceIds("oauth2-resource").accessTokenValiditySeconds(1200)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(2400).redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/authcode").autoApprove(true);
    }  
   @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), defaultAccessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
    }
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }
    }
   ```